# odoo 10 creating a group and associate it to a custom module

Tags: python, odoo

I've created a new module in odoo 10 with différents menus, now I want to create a user who have some menus of this module. So I created the user but when I tried to create the group (in order to associte to the groupe the menu) in the field application I can't find the module that I've created. I've  seted in the manifest file the field application to true and I've checked in the database in ir_module the field is true. Can someone help me please

Comment: what do you mean by users group form you mean the form in menu setting -> usres -> groups ?

Comment: the application field in not m2m to module is m2o to categorie you should use ir.model.security file to define the acces level for you models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In real it's a fake problem because the field "Application" in the form corresponds to an Application category not Application (or module) so a users group (from the menu Setting -> Users -> Groups ) will be applied to a set of Applications (Modules) not for a unique application, so if anyone want to make a group for a unique module he could name the category attribute in the manifest file the as the same of the application (module name)
so try to get the category of your application and choose it from the list.

Comment: Mr Yazid thak you so much for your help. Now I can find it. YOU ARE TRULY AN EXPERT IN ODOO

Comment: Thank you, form your admiration

Comment: I have to thank you :)
(you forgot to upvote my answer ;) )